# Async Updating a TreeView in Winforms using async and await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, treeview, async-await

I have this piece of code running and assigning a new TreeView object to the treeFolders TreeView form object:

```
private async void butLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Task<TreeView> task = Task.Run(() => DirectoryTree.ListDirectory("C:\\"));
        this.treeFolders = await task;

    }
```

I am happy as the code does not block the UI while it goes and recurses the directories and builds a TreeView object.  The problem is that the treeFolders TreeView object on my form remains empty even after running this code.  If I examine the treeFolders object in break mode I can see it does indeed have Nodes for the files and directories so I cannot understand why it is not displaying them.  Is it to do with the fact the TreeView was created on a different threat to the UI thread?  Here is the ListDirectory which seems to work fine and loads all the required directories and files

```
public class DirectoryTree
{
    public static async Task<TreeView> ListDirectory(string path)
    {
        TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
        var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        treeView.Nodes.Add(await CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
        return treeView;

    }

    private static async Task<TreeNode> CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
            foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(await CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
            foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
            return directoryNode;
        }
        catch ( Exception ex)
        {
            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
            return directoryNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't create UI objects on thread pool threads. Instead, create a tree structure in-memory and return it from your `ListDirectory` method, and then have your UI thread create the actual UI objects (`TreeNode`, etc).

Comment: Because you are doing this is the C directory are you sure you aren't getting Unauthorized exceptions? What does your output window say when running the app

Comment: The try catch block deals with the unauthorised exceptions

Comment: In the end I created some POCO's to represent my files and folders, I used AutoMapper to map them to System.IO FileInfo and DirectoryInfo, and I compiled my required data into my POCO's.  Once I had all my directory info I could issue a command to build out my TreeNodes or I could serialize my POCO's and send them to wherever needed.  Thankyou to all who assisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing the *entirety* of the operation in a non-UI thread by calling the top level method call using `Task.Run`.  But you need the code interacting with the UI to run in the UI thread, not a non-UI thread.

You should be performing *only* the long running non-UI operations in a non-UI thread, rather than *all* operations in a non-UI thread.  So this means simply calling `GetFiles` and `GetDirectories` inside of a call to `Task.Run`, leaving the rest of the code (which is your UI code) to run in the UI thread.